# Seeing 'not allowed to load local resource' when running chrome://cache or chrome://view-http-cache

Tags: google-chrome, cache

Would anyone know why I'm getting that message for the URLs above?  Every other chrome URL I've tried (chrome://history, settings...) works fine, but the cache ones suddenly do not.  They worked for as long as I can remember, now they don't.  Is there a Chrome setting I need to tweak, perhaps?

I'm on Chrome version 66, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"chrome://cache" and "chrome://view-http-cache" have been completely removed from chrome. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=837987
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/

> chrome://cache and chrome://view-http-cache internal pages were removed since Chrome 66. You can see that they are not listed in chrome://chrome-urls/ anymore.

You can find all available chrome URLs from here: chrome://chrome-urls/

Comment: Please quote all relevant information in the future

Comment: Are there any replacements for those pages, to see what's been added to the cache?  They were very useful URLs, I'm surprised they're gone now.